# Merging two ul menus that contain child ul with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to merge two unordered lists using `jQuery`. The second list contains child lists. How would I go about doing this? My `HTML` looks like this.

```
<ul class="Menu A">
    <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="Menu B">
    <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul class="childMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Item B1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried the solution here [merge 2 separate menus into a single menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269027/merge-2-separate-menus-into-a-single-menu) but it won't work for child lists.

Comment: Please, post an example of your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

What about simply append the HTML from Menu B after Menu A. So you don't have to worry about looping through multiple levels of list items.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#MenuBoth")
    .html($("#MenuA").html())
    .append($("#MenuB").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Menu A</div>
<ul id="MenuA">
<li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item Four</a></li></ul>
<div>Menu B</div>
<ul id="MenuB">
<li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul class="childMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Item B1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item D</a></li></ul>
<div>Menu Both</div>
<ul id="MenuBoth">
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this route and as I want to keep the two menus intact but together this is perfect. Thank You. How would I get this to fire at 760px and then split apart again when a user increases the size of their browser window?

Comment: You could show/hide the menus according to the browser width. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kmefzzgn/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to see if there is a child item for every this element in your each statement.

```js
var my_merged_list = "";
$('ul li').each(function() {
  var count = $(this).find('ul').length;
  var ll = $(this).find('a:first').text();
  ll = "<a href='#'>" + ll + "</a>";
  my_merged_list = my_merged_list + "<li>" + ll + "</li>";
});
$('ul').remove();
$('body').append('<ul>' + my_merged_list + '</ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Menu A">
  <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="Menu B">
  <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
    <ul class="childMenu">
      <li><a href="#">Item B1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
</ul>
```